# Асинхронность node js

Tags: node.js, асинхронность

Здравствуйте, не понимаю я эту асинхронность, точнее не понимаю в каких случаях код может сделать, то, что от него не хотят. Как расставляются приоритеты между действиями, такими как циклы, функции и т.д
Допустим есть кусок кода:

```
for (j = 1; j < goods.other_color_href.length; j++) {
  getAdditionImages(goods.other_color_href[j], function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  });
}

console.log(3456);
```

Неужели, там где есть цикл обязательно его оборачивать в функцию с кэллбэком? 
В данном примере выполняется, сначала

```
console.log(3456);
```

А потом, то, что уже в цикле, просто, если я захочу произвести какие нибудь операции с теми данными, которые вернул там кэллбэк, допустим обернуть их в ранее объявленный массив и вывести после цикла, то так ничего не получится. 
Также, мне интересно как избежать много вложенных вызовов функций, тут в примере только одна, но а если их с десяток? 
Прошу, помочь, с нодой начал дружить совсем недавно и вопрос уйма. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: и да - если у вас функция синхронная, то необязательно оборачивать ее в коллбэк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для упорядочивания погружения в асинхронность есть как минимум два пути.
Путь самурая -- [вложенные коллбэки](http://habrahabr.ru/post/210330/).
Путь домохозяйки -- [библиотеки типа async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Выбирайте по своему пониманию.

Comment: Времена изменились, и теперь наиболее актуальный путь - использование [промисов][https://learn.javascript.ru/promise]. А наиболее перспективный - использование [генераторов][https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await].

Answer (score 0):

Если так посмотреть, то чем меньше прямых (синхронных) дейсвтий выполняет функция, тем выше КПД у программы. Так что даже минимальные действия, тем более в циклах, советую выносить в отдельные функции.

P.S. Не забывайте про process.nextTick(callable)